# How to limit the weights of gradient descent?

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

Here is the code for calculating the weights. I want to limit the weights to a range, for example (-1, 1)How to do it? Write a class?

```
def coefficients_sgd(train, l_rate, n_epoch):
  coef = [0.0 for i in range(len(train[0]))]
  for epoch in range(n_epoch):
    sum_error = 0
    for row in train:
      yhat = predict(row, coef)
      error = yhat - row[-1]
      sum_error += error**2
      coef[0] = coef[0] - l_rate * error
      for i in range(len(row)-1):
        coef[i + 1] = coef[i + 1] - l_rate * error * row[i]
    print('>epoch=%d, lrate=%.3f, error=%.3f' % (epoch, l_rate, sum_error))
  return coef
```

Comment: If `w` is a weight, process it with `max(min(w, 1), -1)`

Answer (score 0):

This can be viewed as a problem of mapping a number x to the interval (1,-1).  There are many functions which could do this.

`f(x) -> [-1, 1]`

Perhaps use a scaled sigmoid curve centred at the origin: `f(x) = 2*sigmoid(x) -1`

```py
import math

def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))

def normalise(x):
  return 2*sigmoid(x)-1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a simple min-max normalization by doing the following:

```
import numpy as np

coef = np.array(coef)
coef = (coef - min(coef)) / (max(coef) - min(coef))
```

This will ensure all elements inside `coef` are in the interval `(0, 1)`